# Issue with redirection symfony

Tags: symfony

I'm having an issue, here is the project :

```
-> An user answer to a Quizz in POST
-> It submits his answers
-> Calls a controller to flush the POST results
-> Return the user to the homepage (this is the problem, I would like the user to be redirected to that Quizz to see the results).




/**
* Finds and displays a quizz entity.
*
* @Route("/quizz/{id}", name="quizz_answer")
* @Method({"GET", "POST"})
*/
.....
return $this->render('quizz/repondre.html.twig', array(
                        'quizz' => $quizz,
                        'nbrrep' => $questions,
                        'arrayquest' => $arrayQuestions,
                        'delete_form' => $reponseForm->createView(),
));
```

When the user submit his answers it calls :

```
     /**
     * Finds and displays a quizz entity.
     *
     * @Route("/awnser/", name="save_awnsers")
     * @Method({"POST"})
     */
    public function enregistrerReponseSequence(Request $request) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $listereponse = $request->request->all();
        $user = $this->getUser();
        foreach ($listereponse as $lareponse) {
            $reponse = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Reponse_Sequence")->find($lareponse);
            $user->addReponsesSequence($reponse);
        }
        $em->flush();
        return $this->render('base.html.twig');
    }



<form method="POST" action="{{ path("enregistrerReponseSequence")}}" class='form-horizontal'>
```

I would like the user to return to that Quizz to see the results.

I thought about just call the controller to add the results and refreshing the page, but I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: And your question?

Comment: Look at the Route name it's awnser, it should be answer (not sure if this will fix the issue)

Comment: @RumenPanchev It was just a typing mistakes as I renamed everything.

Comment: Can you show us the twig template where u're displaying the form

Comment: I don't see what the problem here is? You haven't added `return $this->redirectToRoute('quizz_answer');` to your `enregistrerReponseSequence` method. You should probably read the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#redirecting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the user where you want. With using the following method:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('your route name');
```

Comment: I've managed to get the Quizz Id and add it to your function, it works perfectly fine !